# React Custom Hook make return Function executable on an Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have created a custom hook for handling the uploads to AWS s3 bucket but I am facing a small problem. I did not want my hook to execute the logic directly so I created an executable function that I am then returning. The only problem is that the state is not being set from inside the `handleUpload` function

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useS3Aws = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [uploadedUrl, setUploadedUrl] = useState("");


  const handleUpload = async (file: any, s3FolderPath: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true); // the problem is here (state not being updated)

    // handle the uploading with AWS s3
    // code ......

    // setting the state with returned live url from s3
    setUploadedUrl("the live url"); // the problem is here (state not being updated)
    console.log(uploadedUrl); // it prints an empty string

    setIsLoading(true); // the problem is here (state not being updated)

  };

  return [
    isLoading,
    uploadedUrl,
    (file: any, s3FolderPath: string) => handleUpload(file, s3FolderPath),
  ] as const;
};

const UploadSong = () => {
  const [isLoading, uploadedUrl, handleUpload] = useS3Aws();

  const handleSong = async () => {

    const file = {
      // object data
    };


    handleUpload(file, "music");

    console.log(uploadedUrl); // it is empty

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Live URL: {uploadedUrl ? uploadedUrl : "No Link"}</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleSong()}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UploadSong;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=55&pc=27#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-tubMNxtNnzmFqtVBtcGBoNijsS0Mq1F4lT5AsE0TJxkOGMwZJ9lkSyvbsL6AyQw1G4ymMzmi3uK1O602mjqDSaissAQHI+mswWSxUvbgng6VX0vBrfEi8CXFhIQkxilUGi0EWqhhbKds2E7s1yaQRC+a2Us+W8CQZEIVRawffRvyRS97UUDpul6W8ti0F1H3oAcvB2Ps4VuI0ACskAwOBHRQMljwTSDFz-CwVyabAWBAIhgDQbVyNdJoPQgL1327P0dQDeAPkjaMGTInR60FZQyQAHisMV1DJHQpLAdQTHFKgkgQExhhwbjPzgAB+MF0R4oI4GGFgADkIDgVTBAAaxYagpKuZSFLgKTnnwGAYCEOAhAAYVFNA7PkHBELnREmmgr0VGoeSsNhQKmLsuAQCQNznM87yhHi2FnNk3LymoPgkAAD0gWAiKQQJ8CCM8qOirggA)

Comment: Is the problem that you're setting setIsUploading to true in every context?

Answer (score 2):

Your hook looks fine, but you aren't using it's returned values right.

```
<button onClick={() => handleSong}>
```

That doesn't actually call `handleSong` on click. This calls a function that merely returns the `handleSong` function on click.

You want:

```
<button onClick={() => handleSong()}>
```

Or if you don't want to pass arguments, you can just:

```
<button onClick={handleSong}>
```

---

One point where you may be confused here:

```
console.log(uploadedUrl); // it is empty
```

When you set state, it's asynchronous. State is being set properly, but any local variables will reflect the previous state, because the re-render has not yet happened. Usually this doesn't matter at all, because [as you can see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mrtikf) the UI updates immediately when you click the working button.

Comment: I think the problem is in useS3Aws hook, because when I am calling `setUploadedUrl` or `setIsLoading` it doesn't update it. you can also console log it.

Comment: It doesn't update because you aren't calling `handleSong`, where the state updates happen. Add a `console.log("Called handleSong")` to the top of `handleSong` in your hook to verify that it's getting invoked.

Comment: The function is getting called because I can console log the link before setting the link in the state. I recreated the hook, to simulate the situation you can try it that way too `<button onClick={() => handleSong()}>`

Comment: I copied and pasted [your code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mrtikf) and the only change I made was to add the button which calls `handleChange` correctly, and it does exactly what you expect it to. So if you are seeing something different, it's a bug in code you have not yet posted.

Comment: See my edit, which explains something that might be tripping you up.